# Small question about symmetric Hadamard matrices

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-matrices, hadamard-matrices

I am trying to understand Hadamard matrix.

My question is simply about whether Hadamard matrix can always be made equivalent (by multiplying row/column by -1 or swapping rows/columns) to a symmetric one?

I only tried a couple but could not find online answers on whether symmetric Hadamard matrix of any order always exists. Thanks for the guidance!